# The Hamiltonian Cycle

Tags: graph-algorithm, backtracking

What is the worst case time complexity of the Hamiltonian cycle problem using backtracking?
Is it O(n!) or O(n^n )? Since I tried to find out the complexity and it's coming out to be O(n×n!) which is more like O(n^n ), and not O(n!).

Answer (score 4):

The brute-force solution for finding a Hamiltonian cycle requires O(n!) work (which is indeed O(n^n), but O(n^n) wouldn't be a tight upper bound).

> A Hamiltonian cycle in a graph `G` with `n` nodes has the form
>   `H = v_1,v_2,v_3,...,v_n,v_1`.

Since `H` includes every node in `G`, we may start our search from any arbitrarily chosen node, say v_1. Subsequently, there are `n-1` candidate nodes to be the second node `v_2` (i.e., all nodes but `v_1` itself); there are `n-2` choices for the third node `v_3` (i.e., all nodes but the chosen candidates for `v_1` and `v_2`), and so on so forth; at the end having candidates for `v_1` to `v_n-1` fixed, there is exactly one remaining candidate for `v_n`.

> (i) This results in a maximum of `(n-1)(n-2)...(2)(1) = (n-1)!`
>   combinations.
>
> (ii) In a naive implementation, checking each combination requires O(n) work; 
>   i.e., for checking whether or not a given combination is
>   a Hamiltonian cycle, we go through the whole sequence of given combination and make sure it has the required properties of a Hamiltonian path.

Hence,

> The overall complexity is `O(n) x (n-1)! = O(n!)`

Of course, we can reduce the required work using a variety of techniques, e.g, branch and bound approaches.